# node.js CPU usage spikes

Tags: node.js, express, profiling, cpu, pm2

I have an `express.js` app running in cluster mode (nodejs cluster module) on a linux production server. I'm using `PM2` to manage this app. It usually uses less than 3% CPU. However, sometimes the CPU usage spikes up to 100% for a short period of time (less than a minute). I'm not able to reproduce this issue. This only happens once a day or two.
Is there any way to find out which function or route is causing the sudden CPU spikes, using PM2? Thanks.

Comment: Have you specified production environment when starting the PM2 process?

Comment: @Alaindeseine Yes, I specified NODE_ENV production in the ecosystem.config.js

Comment: I had the same issue in azure app service using express app

Comment: Did you noticed logs grow up when CPU rise 100%? Or not ?
Have you cheked the size of PM2 logs too ?

Comment: Do you also have memory metrics and do you see anything noteworthy happen to the memory chart at the same time as the CPU chart?

Comment: Memory usage is normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think have some slow synchronous execution on some request in your application.

- add log every request income on middleware and store to elastic search and find what request have long response time or use [newrelic](https://newrelic.com/) (easy way but spend more money).
- use [blocked-at](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blocked-at) to find slow synchronous execution if detect try to use [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) or use lib [workerpool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based purely on my experience with the topic

1. Before going to production make local testing like:

- stress testing.
- longevity testing.

For both tests try to use tool like JMeter where you can put your one/multiple  endpoints and run loads of them in period of time while monitoring CPU & MEMORY Usage.

2. If everything is fine, try also to stop the test and run the api manually try to monitor its behavior, this will help you if there is
   `memory leak` from the APIs themselves
3. Is your app going through `.map()` , `.reduce()`  for huge arrays?
4. Is your app is working significantly better after `reboot`?
   if yes, then you need to suspect that the express app experiencing `memory leak` and Garbage collector trying to clean the mess.
5. If it's possible, try to rewrite the app using [fastify](https://www.fastify.io/), personally, this did not make the app much faster, but able to handle `1.5X` more requests.